# How to create a virtual printer in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, driver, postscript

I want to create a virtual printer driver for Windows. How and where can I start properly? The WDK has some printing drivers examples that do not seems a good introductory. MSDN also doesn't seems to be very helpful for a novice.

There are a lot of virtual printers for Windows out there (mostly they generate PDFs), I wonder if someone could tell my how can I do the same?

Any links to the elaborating documentations are appreciated in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: You might get more help if you said what problem you have that is not addressed by the sample drivers.

Comment: They are a good starting point if you want to develop "real" drivers but they are not as helpful if all you need are "virtual", non-hardware based drivers. The bitmap sample is the most helpful, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I did it (which about 12 years ago) I started with the postscript driver sample, replaced all the postscript-specific stuff (in my case, to write to a bitmap instead of generating postscript commands).

I also wrote a custom print monitor (the driver writes to the spooler, which write to a monitor): my monitor wrote to a file instead of e.g. to the parallel port.

However, printer driver architecture and/or the set of sample drivers may have changed since then.

Comment: Userspace only in post-Vista -- I need to support Windows 2000.

Answer (score 3):

You can look to the 'minidriver' development in the from Microsoft (Microsoft MDT), that might help depending on your exact needs.  If the port you need to deal with (ie: you are going to take the data from an existing printer driver and want to process) you could look to the source code for RedMon.  It doesn't support Vista/Win7 but might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, the 'virtual' (non-hardware) part is the monitor not the driver. The driver controls the format of the output (not the output's location/destination)

Answer (score 3):

This book maybe help you [Developing Drivers with the Windows® Driver Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=10512&locale=en-us)

A list of my links

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx
2. http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/ddk/winddk.mspx
3. http://jungo.com/wdusb.html
4. [https://web.archive.org/web/20130717135254/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff554651.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff554651.aspx)
5. http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Rory/Driver-Development-and-Much-More-With-Mike-Calligaro/

Comment: Well, I already have that book. The problem is not developing drivers, the problem is finding specific information relevant to developing the kind of Virtual Printer drivers that I want.

Comment: Link #4 is now broken unfortunately.  What was that?

Answer (score 2):

One of the drivers you mention is open-source (GPL), maybe you could explore its source or adapt it: http://www.pdfforge.org/products/pdfcreator/download

Comment: Unfortunately (most of it?) is written in Visual Basic. If there were one written in C/C++... :-).

Comment: That may not be the printer driver; its directories like "Version 0.9.8\Printer\Adobe\WinXP2k3-x86\English" are empty, so far as I can see, except for a readme. Maybe the VB is some kind of front end to GhostScript, available separately.

Comment: The contents of "Version 0.9.8\Printer\Adobe\WinXP2k3-x86\English\readme.txt" is "psui.dll", "pscript5.dll", and "pscript.hlp"; these filenames suggests to me that these driver files too were created from the postscript sample driver.

Comment: Would be more helpful to link to the source instead of the company that funds it

Answer (score 2):

Someone else already mentioned PDFCreator.  Here's a more specific link to their code that's creating the printer, port and monitor.  Despite being in VB, I can follow it as someone more used to C++, so I guess you can too.  [modPrinter.bas](http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdfcreator/trunk/InstallPrinter/modPrinter.bas?revision=388&view=markup) does the leg work.  [modMain.bas](http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdfcreator/trunk/InstallPrinter/modMain.bas?revision=311&view=markup), from about line 28 onwards, calls into modPrinter.bas.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Print Port Monitor, associate that port with a printer, and you'll get the data the printer driver sends to the port.

working example of how is it done in Cpp and java can be found here:
http://www.mms-computing.co.uk/uk/co/mmscomputing/device/printmonitor/index.php