# I want to create my own virtual printer which popups my application when print happens

Tags: c#, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a virtual printer in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019036/how-to-create-a-virtual-printer-in-windows)

I want to create my own virtual printer which popups my application when print happens. Also wants to work with network printers.. Can any one help me...?

Thanks in advance..
somesh

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, use `SystemFileWatcher` to monitor $winnt$\System32\spool\ which is where the print job's spooled data is contained in a spool file.

For more info check this [winspool](http://www.undocprint.org/formats/winspool/spl) link.