# Error while installing Windows sample port monitor localmon

Tags: windows, printing, device-driver, wdk

I am trying to install windows sample port monitor(localmon) provided in WDK. But I keep getting error while installing it:

> An error occurred while installing port monitor 'DDK sample port monitor'. Please contact manufacturer for assistance.

I am using following instructions to install it:-

> Open 'Devices and printers' folder. Right click on my targeted printer and choose 'printer properties'. Click the 'Ports' tab, and then click the 'Add Port...' button. On the Printer Ports dialog, click the 'New Port Type...' button. Type the path to the INF file in the text input box, and then click OK.

I am using windows 7, 64-bit version. Following is my INF file.

```
; monitor.inf
;
; Installation inf for printer port monitor
;
; (c) Copyright 2001-2003 DDK Example for print monitor installation
;

[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider=%PMProducer%
ClassGUID={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer

[PortMonitors]
"DDK Sample Port Monitor" = sampleportmon

[sampleportmon]
CopyFiles=@ddklocalmon.dll, @ddklocalui.dll
PortMonitorDll=ddklocalmon.dll

[SourceDisksFiles]
ddklocalmon.dll=1,,
ddklocalui.dll=1,,

[SourceDisksNames]
1="Sample Port Monitor Installation Disk",,,

[Strings]
PMProducer="Sample Port Monitor Company, Inc."
```

Can somebody help me here ?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Were the DLLs built as 64-bit?

Comment: @CareyGregory: Yeah, they were. I built them using the right Build Environment.

Comment: Get a copy of Dependency Walker (64-bit version) and make sure all their dependent DLLs are present on the machine.  http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thanks for your help. DependencyWalker did report a DLL(ieshims.dll) which was unreachable. I had to add a path to, PATH environment variable for it to be reachable. But I am still getting the same error even though DependencyWalker doesn't report any missing DLL now.

Comment: Ieshims.dll is of no concern.  That shows up missing for almost everything.  I just built the localmon port monitor exactly as-is from the WDK.  It installed without problem.  Did you change any of the sample code?  Are you putting ddklocalmon.dll and ddklocalmonui.dll in the same directory with the .INF file?

Comment: @CareyGregory: Yeah, I did that. Actually it was a permissions issue. Method for getting to the Printer Properties with Administrator privileges in windows 7, is via Control Panel, System and Security, Administrative Tools, then right click on Print Management then Run as administrator. Once I did that I was able to install the port monitor. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the link between the localmon, a driver, eg: postscript driver, and the configuration/install(inf?) of the driver and the port monitor and all the files required to do this. I can find bits of information, but no explanation of this whole process. Has anyone got some info on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue. It was a permissions issue. Method for getting to the Printer Properties with Administrator privileges in windows 7, is via Control Panel, System and Security, Administrative Tools, then right click on Print Management then Run as administrator. Once I did that I was able to install the port monitor.

Comment: I assumed all along you were logged in as admin.  Doing any type of driver install or printer management will always require admin privileges.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I was logged in as admin. But windows requires you to explicitly run some programs as admin even though you are logged in as admin.

Comment: Yes, if you have UAC enabled.  For future reference, developing drivers and printer components with AUC enabled is a huge headache.  Recommend you turn UAC off on your development machine.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Hi Carey! Can you please help me with [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459362/error-in-installing-windows-printer-driver) ?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Journey

In the INF file for the port monitor it needs to be directed to install the port monitor DLLs into the Windows\System32.

Following the WDK sample for the Language Port monitor one would think that the [DestinationDirs] directory id might be 66002. Note that the Port Monitor example .inf omits providing a [DestinationDir] section.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/installing-a-print-monitor

The documentation for printer-dirids seems to confirm this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/printer-dirids

```
[DestinationDirs] 
DefaultDestDir = 66002
```

> Dirid: 66002; Purpose: Represents the directory path to additional files to be copied to \System32 of the  local system. See the paragraph following this table.;  Directory Contents: Print monitor files

Note that INFGate tool will provide the following warning:

`.\monitor.inf(xx): warning 8503: (DW22.23.8503) Use of DirID 66002 prevents full remote/point-and-print installation.`

However, this still does not work in practice. Attempting to install the port monitor using 66002 again gives the same error that we started with.

```
Installing Port Monitor
---------------------------
An error occurred installing port monitor 'DDK sample port monitor'. Please contact the  manufacturer for assistance.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

## Solution

The driver documentation has another list of directory ids, and has another one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-dirids

> 11 System directory. This is equivalent to %SystemRoot%\system32 for Windows 2000 and later versions of Windows..

My experience is that using Dirid value of 11 for the System directory seems to work on Windows XP & 10 for Port Monitors.

```
[DestinationDirs] 
DefaultDestDir = 11
```

Note that INFGate will still provide a warning about its discouraged use although it works.
`.\monitor.inf(56): warning 8505: (DW22.23.8505) DirID DefaultDestDir=11 is discouraged.  Should be in 66000-66004 range in order to support remote install.`