# Error in installing windows printer driver

Tags: windows, printing, driver, device-driver

I am trying to install a windows printer driver([OEMUNI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) provided as a sample in WDK(Windows Driver Kit). But I keep getting following error from add printer wizard: "**Printer driver was not installed. Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000002)**". I have tried running the add printer wizard with admin privileges but I still get the same problem.

I am using windows 7, 64-bit version. Can somebody help me here ? Also, what would the error code:0x00000002 signify ?

Following is my INF file:-

```
; OEMDLL.INF
;
; INF file for OEM DLL Customization samples
;
; Copyright 1999-2003 Microsoft Corporation


[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider=%MS%
LayoutFile=ntprint.inf
ClassGUID={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer
DriverVer=6/07/2001,1.0.0.1

;
; Manufacturer section.
;
; This section lists all of the manufacturers 
; that we will display in the Dialog box
;
[Manufacturer]
"Microsoft"=Microsoft, NTamd64, NTia64

;
; Model sections. 
; 
; Each section here corresponds with an entry listed in the
; [Manufacturer] section, above. The models will be displayed in the order
; that they appear in the INF file.
;

[Microsoft]
"PostScript WaterMark Sample"          = INSTALL_WATERMARK.PS
"Unidrv WaterMark Sample"              = INSTALL_WATERMARK.UNI
"OEM PostScript Customization Sample"  = INSTALL_OEMPS
"OEM Unidrv Customization Sample"      = INSTALL_OEMUNI
"OEM UI Customization Sample (PS)"     = INSTALL_OEMUI.PS
"OEM UI Customization Sample (Unidrv)" = INSTALL_OEMUI.UNI

[Microsoft.NTamd64]
"PostScript WaterMark Sample"          = INSTALL_WATERMARK.PS
"Unidrv WaterMark Sample"              = INSTALL_WATERMARK.UNI
"OEM PostScript Customization Sample"  = INSTALL_OEMPS
"OEM Unidrv Customization Sample"      = INSTALL_OEMUNI
"OEM UI Customization Sample (PS)"     = INSTALL_OEMUI.PS
"OEM UI Customization Sample (Unidrv)" = INSTALL_OEMUI.UNI

[Microsoft.NTia64]
"PostScript WaterMark Sample"          = INSTALL_WATERMARK.PS
"Unidrv WaterMark Sample"              = INSTALL_WATERMARK.UNI
"OEM PostScript Customization Sample"  = INSTALL_OEMPS
"OEM Unidrv Customization Sample"      = INSTALL_OEMUNI
"OEM UI Customization Sample (PS)"     = INSTALL_OEMUI.PS
"OEM UI Customization Sample (Unidrv)" = INSTALL_OEMUI.UNI

;
; Installer Sections
;
; These sections control file installation, and reference all files that
; need to be copied. The section name will be assumed to be the driver
; file, unless there is an explicit DriverFile section listed.
;

[INSTALL_WATERMARK.PS]
CopyFiles=@OEM.PPD
CopyFiles=@WMARKPS.INI
CopyFiles=WMARKPS
DataFile=OEM.PPD
DataSection=PSCRIPT_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=PSCRIPT.OEM,PSCRIPT_DATA


[INSTALL_WATERMARK.UNI]
CopyFiles=@OEM.GPD
CopyFiles=@WMARKUNI.INI
CopyFiles=WMARKUNI
DataFile=OEM.GPD
DataSection=UNIDRV_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=UNIDRV.OEM,TTFSUB.OEM,UNIDRV_DATA

[INSTALL_OEMPS]
CopyFiles=@OEM.PPD
CopyFiles=@OEMPS.INI
CopyFiles=OEMPS
DataFile=OEM.PPD
DataSection=PSCRIPT_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=PSCRIPT.OEM,PSCRIPT_DATA

[INSTALL_OEMUNI]
CopyFiles=@OEM.GPD
CopyFiles=@OEMUNI.INI
CopyFiles=OEMUNI
DataFile=OEM.GPD
DataSection=UNIDRV_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=UNIDRV.OEM,TTFSUB.OEM,UNIDRV_DATA

[INSTALL_OEMUI.PS]
CopyFiles=@OEM.PPD
CopyFiles=@OEMUI.INI
CopyFiles=OEMUI
DataFile=OEM.PPD
DataSection=PSCRIPT_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=PSCRIPT.OEM,PSCRIPT_DATA

[INSTALL_OEMUI.UNI]
CopyFiles=@OEM.GPD
CopyFiles=@OEMUI.INI
CopyFiles=OEMUI
DataFile=OEM.GPD
DataSection=UNIDRV_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=UNIDRV.OEM,TTFSUB.OEM,UNIDRV_DATA



; Copy Sections
;
; Lists of files that are actually copied. These sections are referenced
; from the installer sections, above. Only create a section if it contains
; two or more files (if we only copy a single file, identify it in the
; installer section, using the @filename notation) or if it's a color
; profile (since the DestinationDirs can only handle sections, and not
; individual files).
;

[WMARKPS]
WMARKPS.DLL
WMARKUI.DLL

[WMARKUNI]
WMARKUNI.DLL
WMARKUNIUI.DLL

[OEMPS]
OEMPS.DLL

[OEMUI]
OEMUI.DLL

[OEMUNI]
OEMUNI.DLL


;
; Data Sections
;

; These sections contain data that is shared between devices.
;



;
;  Location of source files not in Layout.inf.
;

[SourceDisksNames]
100 = %OEMSample%

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
oemps.dll      = 100,OEMPS\x86
oemui.dll      = 100,OEMUI\x86
oemuni.dll     = 100,OEMUNI\x86
wmarkps.dll    = 100,WaterMark\x86
wmarkuni.dll   = 100,WaterMarkUni\x86
wmarkuniui.dll = 100,WaterMarkUni\x86
wmarkui.dll    = 100,WaterMark\x86

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
oemps.dll      = 100,OEMPS\amd64
oemui.dll      = 100,OEMUI\amd64
oemuni.dll     = 100,OEMUNI\amd64
wmarkps.dll    = 100,WaterMark\amd64
wmarkuni.dll   = 100,WaterMarkUni\amd64
wmarkuniui.dll = 100,WaterMarkUni\amd64
wmarkui.dll    = 100,WaterMark\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.ia64]
oemps.dll      = 100,OEMPS\ia64
oemui.dll      = 100,OEMUI\ia64
oemuni.dll     = 100,OEMUNI\ia64
wmarkps.dll    = 100,WaterMark\ia64
wmarkuni.dll   = 100,WaterMarkUni\ia64
wmarkuniui.dll = 100,WaterMarkUni\ia64
wmarkui.dll    = 100,WaterMark\ia64

[SourceDisksFiles]
OEM.PPD       = 100
OEM.GPD       = 100
WMARKPS.INI   = 100
WMARKUNI.INI  = 100
OEMPS.INI     = 100
OEMUNI.INI    = 100
OEMUI.INI     = 100

;
; Call SetupSetDirectoryId with 66000 to set the target directory at runtime
; (depending on which environment drivers are getting installed)
;

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=66000

;
; Localizable Strings
;
[Strings]
MS="Microsoft DDK Sample"
OEMSample="OEM DLL Print samples"
```

Comment: Well consult the error codes on MSDN and you'll find `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2).

Comment: I am curious: did you managed to use that driver without installing it as a printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

1. did you build the sample first?
2. after you built it, did you put it into the correct folder relative to the `.inf` file?

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Yeah I did build the sample using the corresponding build environment. I am not sure as to how to put into correct folders relative to .INF file. But I did try to put the following files in the same folder : OEMDLL.INF, OEMUNI.DLL, OEM.GPD, OEMUNI.INI . I have posted the INF above. Does this look right to you ? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Manas: all the files named in the `[SourceDisksFiles.*]` sections exist?

Comment: @0xC0000022L is probably right.  You're either missing one of the files listed in the [SourceDisksFiles] section or one of the files they depend on.  Assuming you have no dependencies we don't know about, then most likely you don't have your install directories laid out correctly.  If you're installing on, say, x86, then you need to have all your files in .\OEMPS\x86, .\OEMUI\x86, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys!! Yeah, I had couple of files missing which were mentioned under [SourceDisksFiles.*] section. I added them, so was able to install the driver finally :).

Comment: @CareyGregory: Hi Carey, can I seek your help once more for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491655/generic-text-only-printer-driver-doesnt-work) :)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountere this issue. The reason is: the file oem.gpd includes ttfsub.gpd, which cannot be found in the oemdll directory. But even if we copy ttfsub.gpd from FileRepsoitory to the oemdll directory, the installation will also failure.
However, if you install the bitmap example, you will succeed. So the correct way is to do like bitmap driver...

Answer (score 0):

0x000002 refers to some missing file, that means there is a reference to the file in the inf file but it is not actually present in the driver package. Please check the driver package if all the files mentioned in the inf file are present in the package.