# Windows font rendering

Tags: windows, fonts, rendering

I am writing an application which gets the data stream going to the printer (from [Redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm)) as input. The data stream has text rendered as monochromatic bitmap which printer would use to print it on the paper. I plan to parse this data stream and understand the text going to the printer. My application would parse the data coming from any windows application and going to the printer.

The way I parse the data stream is by matching the pixel information (byte by byte) and if there is an exact match then I can uniquely identify a character. For this I am assuming that all windows applications use same windows renderer to render the font in terms of pixel. Hence I would always get the same sequence of bytes for a particular character from any application if these application(including the ones based on java) use same font and font size for printing their text. Is this a correct assumption or do windows provide various options to applications for rendering the text for printing ?

Also is there a library which I can use for doing character recognition using monochromatic bitmap data ?

NOTE: The printers I am using are ESC/POS compatible printers. The printer driver for these printers send the data to be printed as a monochromatic bitmap.

Comment: Brr, this isn't going to work.  Because for one, printer drivers don't send bitmaps to the printer.  They have their own language, the cheap ones have a very proprietary one.  Select the XPS printer as your default printer, now you got an XPS document that you can easily read.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks for your reply!! Actually I am using ESC/POS printer drivers which send the text to be printed as monochromatic bitmap. I am also able to scan this bitmap data successfully if the printing application is Notepad/Word/Notepad++. But I wanted to make sure that all windows applications would send the same monochromatic bitmap for a given font and font size or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ESC/POS printers, but if you can guarantee the driver always renders text as monochrome bitmaps, your chances of characters being identical for the same font and size are very high, but they are not 100%.  First, you also need to account for rotation, scaling and shearing.  You would need to consider the entire transformation matrix, not just the font size.

There are at least two other failure points I can think of:  1) Text overlaid with transparencies and 2) if the machine has alternate fonts installed with the same names.  For example, common fonts like Helvetica can be obtained from many sources and the characters will not be identical between them.  A third possible failure is an application that ignores the fact that a printer is monochromatic and prints in color or grayscale.  Converting color or grayscale to monochrome will produce different bitmaps for different colors.

As for OCR software, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_optical_character_recognition_software) has a nice comparison chart of OCR SDKs.

Comment: Thanks Carey!! I think I can avoid first 2 failure points in following way: 1) I think you mean something like "watermarking" here, right? The applications I would be running my software against won't be printing any transparencies. 2) I can setup the machine to use fonts from a common source like windows default font file in case of Helvetica. I am not sure about third case, I am trying to see if the applications I would run my software against would print for monochromatic printer or color printer.

Comment: Also, can you please suggest me some source(book, blog, etc) where I can get more information on how does font rendering work on windows for printers ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any good references on Windows font rendering. In a nutshell, text is rendered by print drivers. The driver can draw text either as bitmaps or as polygons using line drawing. Modern fonts are almost always drawn as polygons because bitmaps scale very poorly.  However, a driver can tell Windows it generates only bitmap text, which is what the ESC/POS printers must do.  Rendering bitmap fonts is quite simple and amounts to choosing the bitmap from the font that is closest to the desired size, then bliting it to the device, scaling it if it's not an exact match.

Comment: Thanks Carey for your help!! There is a Java application which I am using. It seems to be using Arial font for printing but the bitmap which it is sending does not exactly match(pixel by pixel) the bitmap generated using Arial on notepad. I am doubting it to be due to 3rd failure case mentioned by you unless you know any other reason which makes Java application generate a different bitmap due to JVM. The application I am mentioning is [FloreantPOS](http://floreantpos.com/) and it is using [Jasper Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasviewer/) for printing. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: It could be many things.  How does it differ?  Is the size the same?

Comment: The bitmap pixels differ e.g. in case of printing 'E', notepad generates a bitmap with 18 rows whereas floreantPOS  generates a bitmap with 17 rows. Regarding size, earlier I thought floreantPOS was printing with size 10(font: Arial). But recently I found something because of which I am not sure. I am looking into the code of floreantPOS to see what size & font it is using. Will let you know when I find something. Thanks a lot for your help :)