# Print generic text-only in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to print text only from a web-application to a thermal printer. Ideally, this functionality will be in a SharePoint Online website for print receipts.

I used `window.print` and tested in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer *(IE9+)* and the printing of a selected text works.

In Google Chrome, however, once pressed the "print" button available in the printing preview, the thermal printer only shows the blank paper.

---

The following source code is just a sample about how we print the text "in a new window"; but, as I saido, in Google Chrome there's not printed.

```
function printThisDocument() {
    try {           
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=1000');
        mywindow.document.write('<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint><head><title>Sticker #1</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('divHidden').innerHTML.trim());
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        setTimeout(function(){ mywindow.print(); mywindow.close(); }, 500);
    } catch (ex) {
        alert('An error ocurred. Try again.');
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

I selected various paper size in the printing preview in Chrome, but only with "Letter" peper size, the thermal printer "prints-actually, uses paper, but not printing results shows".

If I selected other paper sizes, the thermal printer does not use any paper at all.

This situation happens with any highlighted text *(you can try select a text, right click and select "Print")*.

> Chrome prints text as graphics, or at least on all the web sites I
> tried. It uses line drawing to draw the text rather than printing
> actual characters
>
> [**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530764/4092887)

And in this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=381914):

> [...] unfortunately its not possible due to the way chrome prints :(
> chrome cant print plain text [...]

So, I'm running without ideas.

¿Is there a cause/motive about why Chrome cannot print generic text-only?

What I need to archieve is print generic text-only from a SharePoint Online website, using a thermal printer or a sticker machine printer.

I checked another answer about javascipt cannot interact with driver and another server objects, but I also check about java applets, but I'm not sure about how applets works and if this is the only solution - I though applets are outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended by using [QZ Tray 2.0.4](https://qz.io/) *free version*.

Adapting the source code available in his [demo website](https://demo.qz.io/) I did print 
stickers using the browser<sup>1</sup>.

> **NOTE:** If you want use this code, you have to download and install in your computer *"or your client's computer"* QZ Tray 2.0.4 and
>   modify the source code provided here according to your purposes. You
>   might also **[check the official documentation](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-getting-started)**. Also, QZ Tray
>   2.0.4 must be running and the user must accept that QZ Tray 2.0.4 connects to the asigned localhost for check the printer. In this case,
>   I use findDefaultPrinter(true); function for get the default printer.

```
<!-- Required scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dependencies/rsvp-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dependencies/sha-256.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/qz-tray.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /// This is the function I use in the "onclick" attribute.
    function printStuff() {

        var config = getUpdatedConfig();

        var data = ['Raw Data\n', 'More Raw Data\n', 'Even More Raw Data\n'];

        // Print.
        qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
    }

    /// Authentication setup ///
    qz.security.setCertificatePromise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //Preferred method - from server
        //$.ajax("assets/signing/digital-certificate.txt").then(resolve, reject);

        //Alternate method 1 - anonymous
        //resolve();

        //Alternate method 2 - direct
        resolve("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIFAzCCAuugAwIBAgICEAIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n" +
                "MQswCQYDVQQIDAJOWTEbMBkGA1UECgwSUVogSW5kdXN0cmllcywgTExDMRswGQYD\n" +
                "VQQLDBJRWiBJbmR1c3RyaWVzLCBMTEMxGTAXBgNVBAMMEHF6aW5kdXN0cmllcy5j\n" +
                "b20xJzAlBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGHN1cHBvcnRAcXppbmR1c3RyaWVzLmNvbTAeFw0x\n" +
                "NTAzMTkwMjM4NDVaFw0yNTAzMTkwMjM4NDVaMHMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkFBMRMwEQYD\n" +
                "VQQIDApTb21lIFN0YXRlMQ0wCwYDVQQKDAREZW1vMQ0wCwYDVQQLDAREZW1vMRIw\n" +
                "EAYDVQQDDAlsb2NhbGhvc3QxHTAbBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDnJvb3RAbG9jYWxob3N0\n" +
                "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtFzbBDRTDHHmlSVQLqjY\n" +
                "aoGax7ql3XgRGdhZlNEJPZDs5482ty34J4sI2ZK2yC8YkZ/x+WCSveUgDQIVJ8oK\n" +
                "D4jtAPxqHnfSr9RAbvB1GQoiYLxhfxEp/+zfB9dBKDTRZR2nJm/mMsavY2DnSzLp\n" +
                "t7PJOjt3BdtISRtGMRsWmRHRfy882msBxsYug22odnT1OdaJQ54bWJT5iJnceBV2\n" +
                "1oOqWSg5hU1MupZRxxHbzI61EpTLlxXJQ7YNSwwiDzjaxGrufxc4eZnzGQ1A8h1u\n" +
                "jTaG84S1MWvG7BfcPLW+sya+PkrQWMOCIgXrQnAsUgqQrgxQ8Ocq3G4X9UvBy5VR\n" +
                "CwIDAQABo3sweTAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMCwGCWCGSAGG+EIBDQQfFh1PcGVuU1NMIEdl\n" +
                "bmVyYXRlZCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUpG420UhvfwAFMr+8vf3pJunQ\n" +
                "gH4wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUkKZQt4TUuepf8gWEE3hF6Kl1VFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEF\n" +
                "BQADggIBAFXr6G1g7yYVHg6uGfh1nK2jhpKBAOA+OtZQLNHYlBgoAuRRNWdE9/v4\n" +
                "J/3Jeid2DAyihm2j92qsQJXkyxBgdTLG+ncILlRElXvG7IrOh3tq/TttdzLcMjaR\n" +
                "8w/AkVDLNL0z35shNXih2F9JlbNRGqbVhC7qZl+V1BITfx6mGc4ayke7C9Hm57X0\n" +
                "ak/NerAC/QXNs/bF17b+zsUt2ja5NVS8dDSC4JAkM1dD64Y26leYbPybB+FgOxFu\n" +
                "wou9gFxzwbdGLCGboi0lNLjEysHJBi90KjPUETbzMmoilHNJXw7egIo8yS5eq8RH\n" +
                "i2lS0GsQjYFMvplNVMATDXUPm9MKpCbZ7IlJ5eekhWqvErddcHbzCuUBkDZ7wX/j\n" +
                "unk/3DyXdTsSGuZk3/fLEsc4/YTujpAjVXiA1LCooQJ7SmNOpUa66TPz9O7Ufkng\n" +
                "+CoTSACmnlHdP7U9WLr5TYnmL9eoHwtb0hwENe1oFC5zClJoSX/7DRexSJfB7YBf\n" +
                "vn6JA2xy4C6PqximyCPisErNp85GUcZfo33Np1aywFv9H+a83rSUcV6kpE/jAZio\n" +
                "5qLpgIOisArj1HTM6goDWzKhLiR/AeG3IJvgbpr9Gr7uZmfFyQzUjvkJ9cybZRd+\n" +
                "G8azmpBBotmKsbtbAU/I/LVk8saeXznshOVVpDRYtVnjZeAneso7\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "--START INTERMEDIATE CERT--\n" +
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIFEjCCA/qgAwIBAgICEAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgawxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n" +
                "MQswCQYDVQQIDAJOWTESMBAGA1UEBwwJQ2FuYXN0b3RhMRswGQYDVQQKDBJRWiBJ\n" +
                "bmR1c3RyaWVzLCBMTEMxGzAZBgNVBAsMElFaIEluZHVzdHJpZXMsIExMQzEZMBcG\n" +
                "A1UEAwwQcXppbmR1c3RyaWVzLmNvbTEnMCUGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYYc3VwcG9ydEBx\n" +
                "emluZHVzdHJpZXMuY29tMB4XDTE1MDMwMjAwNTAxOFoXDTM1MDMwMjAwNTAxOFow\n" +
                "gZgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIDAJOWTEbMBkGA1UECgwSUVogSW5kdXN0\n" +
                "cmllcywgTExDMRswGQYDVQQLDBJRWiBJbmR1c3RyaWVzLCBMTEMxGTAXBgNVBAMM\n" +
                "EHF6aW5kdXN0cmllcy5jb20xJzAlBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGHN1cHBvcnRAcXppbmR1\n" +
                "c3RyaWVzLmNvbTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBANTDgNLU\n" +
                "iohl/rQoZ2bTMHVEk1mA020LYhgfWjO0+GsLlbg5SvWVFWkv4ZgffuVRXLHrwz1H\n" +
                "YpMyo+Zh8ksJF9ssJWCwQGO5ciM6dmoryyB0VZHGY1blewdMuxieXP7Kr6XD3GRM\n" +
                "GAhEwTxjUzI3ksuRunX4IcnRXKYkg5pjs4nLEhXtIZWDLiXPUsyUAEq1U1qdL1AH\n" +
                "EtdK/L3zLATnhPB6ZiM+HzNG4aAPynSA38fpeeZ4R0tINMpFThwNgGUsxYKsP9kh\n" +
                "0gxGl8YHL6ZzC7BC8FXIB/0Wteng0+XLAVto56Pyxt7BdxtNVuVNNXgkCi9tMqVX\n" +
                "xOk3oIvODDt0UoQUZ/umUuoMuOLekYUpZVk4utCqXXlB4mVfS5/zWB6nVxFX8Io1\n" +
                "9FOiDLTwZVtBmzmeikzb6o1QLp9F2TAvlf8+DIGDOo0DpPQUtOUyLPCh5hBaDGFE\n" +
                "ZhE56qPCBiQIc4T2klWX/80C5NZnd/tJNxjyUyk7bjdDzhzT10CGRAsqxAnsjvMD\n" +
                "2KcMf3oXN4PNgyfpbfq2ipxJ1u777Gpbzyf0xoKwH9FYigmqfRH2N2pEdiYawKrX\n" +
                "6pyXzGM4cvQ5X1Yxf2x/+xdTLdVaLnZgwrdqwFYmDejGAldXlYDl3jbBHVM1v+uY\n" +
                "5ItGTjk+3vLrxmvGy5XFVG+8fF/xaVfo5TW5AgMBAAGjUDBOMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSQ\n" +
                "plC3hNS56l/yBYQTeEXoqXVUXDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQDRcZNwPqOqQvagw9BpW0S\n" +
                "BkOpXjAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAJIO8SiNr9jpLQ\n" +
                "eUsFUmbueoxyI5L+P5eV92ceVOJ2tAlBA13vzF1NWlpSlrMmQcVUE/K4D01qtr0k\n" +
                "gDs6LUHvj2XXLpyEogitbBgipkQpwCTJVfC9bWYBwEotC7Y8mVjjEV7uXAT71GKT\n" +
                "x8XlB9maf+BTZGgyoulA5pTYJ++7s/xX9gzSWCa+eXGcjguBtYYXaAjjAqFGRAvu\n" +
                "pz1yrDWcA6H94HeErJKUXBakS0Jm/V33JDuVXY+aZ8EQi2kV82aZbNdXll/R6iGw\n" +
                "2ur4rDErnHsiphBgZB71C5FD4cdfSONTsYxmPmyUb5T+KLUouxZ9B0Wh28ucc1Lp\n" +
                "rbO7BnjW\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");
    });

    qz.security.setSignaturePromise(function(toSign) {
        return function(resolve, reject) {
            //Preferred method - from server
            //$.ajax("/secure/url/for/sign-message?request=" + toSign).then(resolve, reject);

            //Alternate method - unsigned
            resolve();
        };
    });


    /// Connection ///
    function launchQZ() {
        if (!qz.websocket.isActive()) {
            window.location.assign("qz:launch");
            //Retry 5 times, pausing 1 second between each attempt
            startConnection({ retries: 5, delay: 1 });
        }
    }

    function startConnection(config) {
        if (!qz.websocket.isActive()) {
            qz.websocket.connect(config).then(function() {
                findDefaultPrinter(true); /* Instead of findVersion(); */
            }).catch(handleConnectionError);
        } else {
            displayAlert('An active connection with QZ already exists.');
        }
    }

    function endConnection() {
        if (qz.websocket.isActive()) {
            qz.websocket.disconnect().then(function() {
                alert('Desconectado');
            }).catch(handleConnectionError);
        } else {
            displayAlert('No active connection with QZ exists. Openinig a new one.');
            startConnection();
        }
    }

    // Recargar la página para iniciar la conexión.
    function restartConnection() {
        startConnection({ retries: 5, delay: 1 });
    }

    /// Detection ///
    function findDefaultPrinter(set) {
        qz.printers.getDefault().then(function(data) {
            displayAlert("La impresora (" + data + ") ha sido encontrada.\nAhora puede proceder a imprimir stickers.");
            if (set) { setPrinter(data); }
        }).catch(createConsoleLog);
    }

    /// Raw Printers ///
    function printEPL() {
        var config = getUpdatedConfig();

        /* Información de prueba. */
        var printData = [
            '\nN\n',
            'q609\n',
            'Q203,26\n',
            'B5,26,0,1A,3,7,152,B,"1234"\n',
            'A310,26,0,3,1,1,N,"SKU 00000 MFG 0000"\n',
            'A310,56,0,3,1,1,N,"QZ PRINT APPLET"\n',
            'A310,86,0,3,1,1,N,"TEST PRINT SUCCESSFUL"\n',
            'A310,116,0,3,1,1,N,"FROM SAMPLE.HTML"\n',
            'A310,146,0,3,1,1,N,"QZ.IO"\n',
            '\nP1,1\n'
        ];

        qz.print(config, printData).catch(createConsoleLog);
    }

    /// Page load ///
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.readingWeight = false;       
        startConnection();      
        // ¡La conexión con la impresora se establece cuando la conexión sea exitosa!
        alert('============================================\n' +
              '              You're using QZ Tray software.\n' + 
              '============================================\n' +
              'For sticker printing, you mus install\n' +
              'QZ Tray 2.0.4\n\n' + 
              'QZ Tray 2.0.4 will detect the default printer.\n\n' +
              'Click on "Accept" and\n' +
              'Wait until your printer's name is shown.');
    });

    qz.websocket.setClosedCallbacks(function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);

        if (evt.reason) {
            displayAlert("Connection closed:" + evt.reason);
        }
    });

    qz.websocket.setErrorCallbacks(handleConnectionError);

    /// Helpers ///
    function handleConnectionError(err) {
        if (err.target != undefined) {
            if (err.target.readyState >= 2) { //if CLOSING or CLOSED
                createConsoleLog("Connection to QZ Tray was closed");
            } else {
                createConsoleLog("A connection error occurred, check log for details");
                console.error(err);
            }
        } else {
            createConsoleLog(err);
        }
    }

    function createConsoleLog(err) {
        console.error(err);
        displayAlert(err);
    }

    function displayAlert(msg, css) {
        alert(msg);
    }

    /// QZ Config ///
    var cfg = null;
    function getUpdatedConfig() {
        if (cfg == null) {
            cfg = qz.configs.create(null);
        }

        updateConfig();
        return cfg
    }

    // Los parámetros estarán como "undefined" ya que no existen en mi código final.
    function updateConfig() {
        var pxlSize = null;
        var pxlMargins = $("#pxlMargins").val(); // = undefined.
        var jobName = "Impresión Sticker";

        cfg.reconfigure({
            altPrinting: $("#rawAltPrinting").prop('checked'),
            encoding: $("#rawEncoding").val(),
            endOfDoc: $("#rawEndOfDoc").val(),
            perSpool: $("#rawPerSpool").val(),
            colorType: $("#pxlColorType").val(),
            copies: 1,
            density: $("#pxlDensity").val(),
            duplex: $("#pxlDuplex").prop('checked'),
            interpolation: $("#pxlInterpolation").val(),
            jobName: jobName,
            margins: pxlMargins,
            orientation: $("#pxlOrientation").val(),
            paperThickness: $("#pxlPaperThickness").val(),
            printerTray: $("#pxlPrinterTray").val(),
            rasterize: $("#pxlRasterize").prop('checked'),
            rotation: $("#pxlRotation").val(),
            scaleContent: $("#pxlScale").prop('checked'),
            size: pxlSize,
            units: $("input[name='pxlUnits']:checked").val()
        });
    }

    function setPrinter(printer) {
        var cf = getUpdatedConfig();
        cf.setPrinter(printer);
    }

</script>
<!--FIN-->
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Test made in Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.90 (Build oficial) (64 bits).